# Horizontal append in for loop?

Tags: csv, pandas, merge, glob

I have a for loop iterating over a folder of one column csv's using glob, it makes some adjustments and then appends the results to a list and saves to a new csv, it resembles:

```
data= []
infiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
for file in infiles:
    df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(file)
    (assorted adjustments)
    data.append(df)
fullpanel = pd.concat(panel)
fullpanel.to_csv('data.csv')
```

The problem is that makes one long column, I need each column (of differing lengths) added next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add parameter `axis=1` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for columns added next to each other. Also you can change `pd.io.parsers.read_csv` to [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and `panel` to `data` in `concat`.

```
data= []
infiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
for file in infiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    (assorted adjustments)
    data.append(df)
fullpanel = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
fullpanel.to_csv('data.csv')
```